# cakePHP 3.3 internationalization

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How can I set multiple language in case text is in array?

I know that if I use this

```
<?= __('username')?>
```

and in directory /src/Locale/de_DE/default.po
I have written following

```
msgid "username"
msgstr "benutzer"
```

It's gonna change username to benutzer if I set language to de_DE (german)

But what to do if I have this

```
<?= $this->Form->input('password',['label' =>'Password']); ?>
```

and I would like to change label Password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
$this->Form->input('password', ['label' => __('Password')]);
```

The __() function simply returns the translated string [(more info)](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#__). In your example you used

```
<?= ... ?>
```

which is equivalent to

```
<?php echo ... ?>
```

Comment: There is no true anymore for __(). Not since 2.0.0 :)

Comment: @mark You're right, I'm still maintaining some CakePHP 1.x projects that use the 'true' parameter. Updated answer.